# Should I pronounce the singular "Irishman" and the plural "Irishmen" identically?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, homophones, ipa, dialects

Can someone tell me how to pronounce the following:

- Irishman/Irishmen

I have read carefully, according to the online [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/irishman), the pronunciation of words like Irishman/Irishmen: the singular is the same as the plural, both are  phonemically**/ˈʌɪrɪʃmən/** in standard IPA.

Please check Merriam-Webster, which uses a non-standard, custom pronunciation scheme: [Irishman](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Irishman) = **ī-rish-mən** and [Irishmen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Irishmen) = **ī-rish-mən**

For example, here's the entry for *Irishman/Irishmen* from [the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irishman?q=irishmen), which is also using IPA to denote which broad phonemes people hear in their minds when these words are said aloud:

> > **Irishman**
> >
> > *noun* [ C ]: **UK**  /ˈaɪə.rɪʃ.mən/ **US** ​ /ˈaɪə.rɪʃ.mən/ **ᴘʟᴜʀᴀʟ** -men **UK** ​ /-mən/ **US​**

However, several native speaker experts from EL&U assure me that in natural speech the two pronunciations are different:

> - In practice they will end up the same. When a native speaker is enunciating carefully (ie artificially), they will sound different: the singular will rhyme with Spider-man and the plural (which is the sound you’re actually hearing for both) with Goldman in Goldman Sachs. @Dan Bron ([link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423742/how-to-pronounce-irishman-dutchman#comment1014556_423742))
> - Did you google *pronounce irishmen* and *pronounce irishman*
>     It's a subtle difference. @aparente001 ([link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423742/how-to-pronounce-irishman-dutchman#comment1014557_423742))

What is the actual case here: should *Irishman* and *Irishmen* be true homophones in reality?

Comment: In practice they will end up the same. When a native speaker is enunciating carefully (ie artificially), they will sound different: the singular will rhyme with *Spider-man* and the plural (which is the sound you’re actually hearing for both) with *Goldman* in *Goldman Sachs*. In fact, Jerry Seinfeld, a comedian, does a bit about pronouncing Spiderman as *Spidermuhn*, in accordance with how typical Jewish surnames ending in *-man* are pronounced.

Comment: @DanBron I would say that a native speaker enunciating carefully will pronounce the _singular_ to rhyme with ‘Goldman’ and the plural with a clear /ε/ to rhyme with _men_. I’ve never heard a native speaker pronounce _Irishman/Dutchman/Frenchman/ABCman_ (where _ABC_ is a nationality) to rhyme with _Spiderman/Superman/XYZman_ (where _XYZ_ is a superhero).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Maybe it’s an NYC thing? Goldman doesn’t rhyme with Spiderman, but artificially-enunciated Irishman does. Or maybe I have a tin ear.

Comment: @Araucaria - You don't have to pronounce them differently if you don't want to.  I do.  I checked two youtube pronunciations and one does (emmasaying) and one doesn't.

Comment: Sir,i have read carefully, according to an oxford book, the pronounciation of words like Irishman/men: the singular is the same as the plural.

Comment: Please check it [Irishman](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Irishman) = ī-rish-mən and [Irishmen](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Irishmen) = ī-rish-mən

Comment: @Araucaria - I was doubtful whether it was okay to reopen -- I was thinking maybe the OP hadn't done their due diligence (show your research). What do you think about that? // Links: singular: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TckKJapVlsw; plural: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKgdz1lBsHk.  It's definitely subtle. // "adamant that the two words have different pronunciations" -- not quite. I'm only saying that when I'm speaking in a normal (not rushed) way, I make a difference, or at least I think of it as different!  But my (German) spouse can't tell the difference in a speech test!  Note, ...

Comment: @aparente001 Erm, well OP had done some research, hadn't they? They'd looked the two words up in  various dictionaries. That would seem to be sensible research. However, intuitively doubting the accuracy of the dictionaries, they came to get some expert authentification. You've not only doubted the veracity of the dictionaries, you've closed the question because it seems plain to you that a little googling would have shown the dictionaries to be *wrong*. Your links, however, make no sense :( ...

Comment: @aparente001 ... You've linked to two completely different individuals  both saying the *singular* 'Irishman' -- very unnaturally it might be added. The fact that these two individuals use a different vowel when unnaturally saying the singular word *Irishman* does not provide evidence that the pronunciation of *Irishman* and *Irishmen* are different!!! (either in those varieties of English, or in standard American or British Englishes).

Comment: @Araucaria - Sorry, got my links mixed up, evidently.  Let's try that again.  Singular: https://youtu.be/TckKJapVlsw, plural: https://youtu.be/rmANJ9QHu-4.

Comment: She has a bit of a secondary stress on the last syllable.  I only found this in one dictionary audio clip: vocabulary.com.  (Unfortunately they don't provide an audio clip of the plural.) // I found one dictionary that sort of gives clips: http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/Irishman.  But for the plural you only get the last syllable.  www.definitions.net appears to give audio clips of both but I can't get them to play.

Comment: For me, the difference between Irishman and Irishmen is the difference between [*sermon*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sermon) /ˈsərmən/ and [*vermin*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vermin) /ˈvərmɪn/. This is a distinction which not all native speakers make, and is quite hard to hear even when they do make it. But this would explain why some people insist they're pronouncing them differently.

Comment: @PeterShor That's the classic distinction between *Rosa’s* with the mid central unrounded vowel [ə] versus *Roses* with the close central unrounded vowel [ɨ]. Spoken slowly and carefully, meaning unnaturally, I (can) produce the ever so slightly different phonetic sounds there you mention. I'm far from sure I normally do so in connected speech, and when listening to others my brain would fill in the word that contextually “should” be there no matter which had been said. So I can’t even tell whether those are separate phonemes for me; they may well not be. Reduction is such a variable thing.

Comment: @Araucaria I’ve reöpened and even begun a stab at an answer. I’m concerned that it may be hard for laymen to follow because of the technical nuances needed for a strict/narrow phonetic transcription to represent what people truly say instead of for the loose/broad phonemic transcriptions they’re accustomed to seeing in dictionaries, which are only idealized notions that depart from reality in ways usually known only to professionals or ardent enthusiasts. For example see [*lamb*](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/lamb), and [this keyboard](http://ipa.typeit.org/full/).

Comment: @tchrist: I *think* I usually make this distinction in connected speech, although in the specific case of *Irishman(men)* and *sermon/vermin* the vowels would probably both get reduced to a syllabic [n̩]. It still explains why people think they're pronouncing them differently — internally they are separate phonemes, even though they both get reduced to [n̩]. Just like *prince/prints* or *bidder/bitter*.

Comment: I asked a friend who was visiting to record her voice.  Neither she nor I could hear a difference until I slowed it down 20%!  In this clip you will hear the normal tempo and then the -20 tempo.  https://instaud.io/1Ags

Comment: @PeterShor You know, Peter, you could always mosey on over to [Ed Flemming](http://web.mit.edu/flemming/www/)’s office and see what he has to say about all this. :)

Comment: @PeterShor How's it for you with *policeman/policemen*?

Comment: @aparente001 Ah, I see! Hmm - got to be honest, don't think her pronunciation's up to much! (She's saying the word in isolation - let me check out more of her pron ...)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70864/discussion-on-question-by-wuqt-how-to-pronounce-the-singular-irishman-and-the).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## As one word: *both* [ˈʌɪ̯ɻəʃmn̩]

Yes, they really are homophones — but only when said as compound words rather than as two separate words in succession. As compound words, the American pronunciation of *Irishman* and *Irishmen* alike is usually just [ˈʌɪ̯ɻəʃmn̩] in connected speech, no matter whether singular or plural. Only the stressed syllable has a distinctive, non-reduced vowel, as is the normal case in English.

The other two syllables are very short, and the final syllable has been further reduced so that it has only a syllabic consonant [n̩], not a vowel proper.

## As two words: [əˌnʌɪ̯ɻəʃ ˈmæə̯n] *vs*. [səˌmʌɪ̯ɻəʃ ˈmɛn]

It’s the unstressed reduction that makes all the difference. These are pronounced differently than one would pronounce *“an Irish man”* [əˌnʌɪ̯ɻəʃ ˈmæə̯n]
or *“some Irish men”* [səˌmʌɪ̯ɻəʃ ˈmɛn].

Only when separate words giving *man/men* primary stress does it work differently, because that’s the only way for the distinction between [ˈmæə̯n] and [ˈmɛn] to appear. Plus the singular *man* is a little bit longer because of its stressed [æə̯] [diphthong under *ae*-tensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//%C3%A6/_raising#/%C3%A6/_tensing_before_/m/_and_/n/), something that doesn’t happen in the unstressed part of compound words.

---

#### But what about Rosa’s roses?

Peter Shor comments that for him, the singular *Irishman* has what is in effect the unstressed vowel of *Rosa’s*, while the plural *Irishmen* has what is in effect the unstressed vowel of *roses*.

- the singular *Irishm**a**n* with the [***mid* central unrounded vowel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel#Mid_central_unrounded_vowel) [ə] of *Rosa’s*
- the plural *Irishm**e**n* with the [***close* central unrounded vowel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_central_unrounded_vowel) [ɨ] of *roses*

For many people, [ə] and [ɨ] are alternate phonetic allophones of the same underlying phoneme /ə/. It is a matter of some controversy whether there actually exists a distinct /ɨ/ phoneme instead of just an [ɨ] allophone of /ə/; for those who hear *Rosa’s* and *roses* as different words, there may well be. For those who do not, there isn’t.

For more about this, see the highly cited 2007 linguistics paper [“*Rosa’s roses:* reduced vowels in American English”](http://web.mit.edu/flemming/www/paper/rosasroses.pdf) by MIT’s Edward Flemming and CalTech’s Stephanie Johnson.

That same unstressed vowel [ɨ] might also occur in some utterances of *Irish*, so [ˈʌɪ̯ɻɨʃ]. The degree of vowel reduction in English unstressed syllables is always highly variable, and words said in isolation don’t sound the same as words said in connected speech.

---

#### Notational Notes

If we’re going to discuss actual sounds, and it seems we must, then we’ll need to use the phonetic notation used by specialists not the phonemic notation used by dictionaries. This can be quite complicated, but it’s the only way to show what we mean in writing. I provide three references to help reading, writing, and listening:

- [READING] The Wikipedia page on the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=international+phonetic+alphabet&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).
- [WRITING] A way to type those symbols using the [Full IPA Keyboard](http://ipa.typeit.org/full/).
- [LISTENING] The University of Edinburgh’s incredibly useful Sound Comparisons website as mentioned by phoneticist John Wells [on his blog](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/07/sound-comparisons.html). See for example how these words are actually said in different accents including Irish ones, with narrow phonetic transcriptions and **actual sound clips** provided:

  - [white](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/white)
  - [lamb](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/lamb)
  - [daughter](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/daughter)
  - [naked](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/naked)

Comment: Remember how I'm supposed to learn phonetic notation at some point?  (Re Spanish Language SE.)  Which one?  Also is there a tutorial or something that will make it relatively painless?